# Unix: How to one-way-sync directory with FTP directory

Tags: mac, unix, sync, terminal, ftp

Is there a good command I can run from the Terminal that will one-way sync a directory with an FTP directory in a smart way?

I'd like it to for example delete all files on the FTP that no longer exist locally and to only upload files that are new or changed.

Any clues?

***Note:*** Have tried to ask this before and was told `rsync` works with SFTP, which is good, but I have to work with a server that only supports FTP

Answer (score 3):

You can mount an FTP host through `fuse`, much like sshfs.

```
curlftpfs -o allow_other ftp://myusername:mypassword@ftp.mydomain.com myftp
```

Once mounted, you can run rsync against it.

Comment: Note that `rsync` might try to calculate the checksum of each file, which will effectively download everything from the mounted ftp directory. Look at the manpage, probably you will want `--size-only`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist in 10.4 at least, but I can try this out once I have a Mac I can install MacPorts on.

Comment: @Svish: [`brew`](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) `install` [`curlftpfs`](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) worked for me.